# How to form 5 minutes open high low close values from a continuous coming data c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a websocket api which continuously giving me data per second. My goal is to form a 5 minutes open close high low based in this data.

This is Python code, they are doing same in Python: https://gist.github.com/oldmonkABA/f73f5d67bcf85316ac0470919bf54e17

I tried like below `OnTick` method got calls every 1 second with every second data like this:

```
{"InstrumentToken":260105,"LastPrice":23616.6,"Timestamp":"2020-10-16T16:35:01"}
```

So I will get same json with different LastPrice and Timestamp after every second like:

```
{"InstrumentToken":260105,"LastPrice":23620,"Timestamp":"2020-10-16T14:38:02"}

{"InstrumentToken":260105,"LastPrice":23622,"Timestamp":"2020-10-16T14:38:03"}
```

and so on till:

```
{"InstrumentToken":260105,"LastPrice":23644,"Timestamp":"2020-10-16T14:39:59"}
```

Now in below object `latestTickData` I'm collecting all this data and expected output is:

open = 23616.6 as it's a very starting price based on "Timestamp":"2020-10-16T14:35:01".

close = 23644 based on its last 5 minutes price "Timestamp":"2020-10-16T14:39:59".

high = I can use MAX(of all 5 minutes data).

low = I can use MIN(of all 5 minutes data)

C# code:

```
private static void OnTick(Tick TickData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tick " + Utils.JsonSerialize(TickData));

    var latestTickData = new MyObject()
    {
        InstrumentID = TickData.InstrumentToken,
        Close = TickData.LastPrice,
        High = TickData.LastPrice,
        Low = TickData.LastPrice,
        Open = TickData.LastPrice,
        TimeStamp = TickData.Timestamp.HasValue ? TickData.Timestamp.Value : DateTime.Now
    };
```

now I will collect a new data every second into `latestTickData`.

I want to form a 5 minutes open close high low based in this data.

I was thinking to do like group by on timestamp and min max function for finding low and high but the code is not working.

I tried with this code, but this code is outside of ontick method on calculating ongoing data:

```
var resultSet = MydataList.GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(5))
           .Select(gr =>
          new
          {
              StartOfPeriod = gr.Key,
              Low = gr.Min(item => item.Low),
              High = gr.Max(item => item.High),
              Open = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).First().Open,
              Close = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).Last().Close
          });


public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes)
    {
        int oldMinutes = TimeStamp.Minute;
        int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

        DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(TimeStamp.Year, TimeStamp.Month, TimeStamp.Day, TimeStamp.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

        return startOfPeriod;
    }
```

Comment: *"I want to identify open close high low data"* What's that?

Comment: My goal is to form a 5 minutes open close high low based in this data.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Can you define what is an open data? A high data? A low data? A close data?

Comment: ok sir let me updated question with output

Comment: What is your _question_? Please include a [mcve], explain what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with. LINQ operates on enumerations (sequences) of data items; there's nothing in your post that shows any data structure that accumulates the data you seem to want to process, never mind anything that shows your attempt to process it.

Comment: i want to form latest 5 minutes data only like currently its 12:55 then i want to check data from 12:50:01 to 12:54:59 and find out open , high , low and close

Comment: added details now into question with example :) please do needful thank you so much

Comment: Sounds like some kind of "Time Series" - are you on azure?

Comment: yes i can use azure service please suggest but its related to IOT data right?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/time-series-insights/ Yes, seems to be related to IoT, ... but I was under the impression, there has been a "multipurpose" TimeSeries module ... I hope it's not gone ...

Comment: this is python code they are doing same in python -
https://gist.github.com/oldmonkABA/f73f5d67bcf85316ac0470919bf54e17 any help for c#?

Comment: I think you need to look into [Rx.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive). It has operations which may be helpful to you. P.S.: DO NOT SEARCH FOR RX.NET ITSELF!!!! I have linked to github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and it would depend on how often you need to read the data, and if it's worth updating a cache every tick, or you need a timer to keep it refreshed, or you just want to calculate it on the fly.

Anyway, I have chosen a *queue* to manage the series, I have also chosen to update the cache on every tick (rightly or wrongly). You could as easily just use a list, and filter / query in real-time, I'll leave all those details up to you.

**Given**

```
public class Tick
{
   public int Instrument { get; set; }
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
   public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
   private readonly Queue<Tick> _queue = new Queue<Tick>();
   public decimal High { get; private set; }
   public decimal Low { get; private set; }
   public decimal Open { get; private set; }
   public decimal Close { get; private set; }

   public void Add(Tick tick)
   {
      _queue.Enqueue(tick);
      Update();
   }

   public void Update()
   {
      var age = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
      while (_queue.Any() && _queue.Peek().TimeStamp < age)
         _queue.Dequeue();

      High = _queue.Max(x => x.LatestPrice);
      Low = _queue.Min(x => x.LatestPrice);
      Open = _queue.LastOrDefault()?.LatestPrice ?? 0;
      Close = _queue.FirstOrDefault()?.LatestPrice ?? 0;

   }
}
```

A dictionary to hold it

```
private Dictionary<int,Data> _instruments = new Dictionary<int, Data>();
```

**Usage**

```
// add data
if(!_instruments.TryGetValue(tick.Instrument, out var data))
   _instruments.Add(tick.Instrument, data = new Data());
data.Add(tick);

...

var Ohcl = _instruments[TickData.Instrument];

// example reading the data
Console.WriteLine(Ohcl.High);
```

If you wanted to calculate it on the fly

```
public class Data
{
   private readonly Queue<Tick> _queue = new Queue<Tick>();
   public decimal High => _queue.Max(x => x.LatestPrice);
   public decimal Low => _queue.Min(x => x.LatestPrice);
   public decimal Open => _queue.LastOrDefault()?.LatestPrice ?? 0;
   public decimal Close => _queue.FirstOrDefault()?.LatestPrice ?? 0;

   public void Add(Tick tick)
   {
      _queue.Enqueue(tick);
      Update();
   }

   public void Update()
   {
      var age = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
      while (_queue.Any() && _queue.Peek().TimeStamp < age)
         _queue.Dequeue();
   }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This is not meant to be a complete solution, it lacks sanity checks and a whole bunch of details that might be relevant to you. The performance and efficiency is also at your discretion*</sub>

Comment: let me try this thank you so much , what if we want to do it on the fly where we got every second data in on_tiick() method ?

Comment: i have used on the fly code sorry quick question how and where to get actual 5 mint data? in my own class i took variables then updated method and already have tick method there i added    _queue.Enqueue(tick);
      Update();

Comment: @Neo its a little hard to keep progressing with this as this was only an example and it really depends on what you are doing and want to do and how you are doing it. Maybe just play around with it, and see how you go, and if you have deeper questions it might be worth while asking another question... But i suggest looking at the solve i have shown and trying to understand it, and just play

Comment: Not criticism, just pointing out to OP: This is _not_ threadsafe! The methods are not atomic, so you might want to consider this in your application.

Comment: @Fildor yes very good point.

Comment: ok got you thank you

Comment: i will add each tick data into cosmos db but not sure how to fetch only recent 5 minutes data ?

Comment: @Neo a database makes this a completely different problem. you would just do a query for the last 5 minutes. Mind you its the most sane approach.

Comment: _"i will add each tick data into cosmos db but not sure how to fetch only recent 5 minutes data ?"_ - That would be another question and should be asked sepearately. :)

Comment: let me ask another question and put my complete code there and my issue too :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385556/unable-to-get-exact-latest-5-minutes-data-from-cosmos-db-c-sharp

Comment: The General  @Fildor  please try to help me it will be great help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
AS @Cid has mentioned ,first method assumes that data comes in regular intervals,but most likely that would never be the case and there is a big possibility of error.The best way is to try the second method where you have two variables and compare the timestamps.

---

There are multiple workarounds on this problem.You mentioned that you get data every 1s,then for example you can have a variable that counts how many pieces of data have you collected:

```
//before first element has come
int numberOfData=0;
```

and after every thick you just increment numberOfData.When numberOfData is 300(5*60s) then five minutes have past assuming that you get data every one second.

---

Another method is that you have two variables firstData and lastData that are initially set to null.Then you assign first TickData that comes to firstData,and than just compare a timestamp between firstData and the oncoming new TickData objects.When the difference is 5 minutes you can assign that object to lastData.

Comment: This will work as long as you perfectly fetch datas every `1.0000` seconds. Imagine it takes `1.1` seconds to get them, you'll have 10% of datas that aren't supposed to be there

Comment: Yes you have a point,thanks for commenting.

Comment: sometimes we might not get data from server for all seconds i mean  leaving 1-2 seconds also we can get