# How to get exact latest 5 minutes data from cosmos db in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb

I have a webjob which run continuously and read data from web socket api.

Below is the code which automatically run after every 1 second and add tick data into cosmos db.

```
private static void OnTick(Tick TickData)
        {

            var latestTickData = new MyObject()
            {
                InstrumentID = TickData.InstrumentToken,
                Close = TickData.LastPrice,
                High = TickData.LastPrice,
                Low = TickData.LastPrice,
                Open = TickData.LastPrice,
                TimeStamp = TickData.Timestamp.HasValue ? TickData.Timestamp.Value : DateTime.Now
            };

            // add data into cosmos

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Program.documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("tickerDatabase", "tickerContainer"), latestTickData);
            }).Wait();
        }
```

Now I want to read most recent 5 minutes data and take open high low close values.

For latest 5 minutes data currently I'm running a timer job every 5 minutes which read data from cosmos and calculate open high low close but issue is time here.

If timer job runs 1 minute late also the widow of that data will change and getting wrong values.

My question is, how to get exact 5 minutes latest data from cosmos?

Current timer job code -

myobject.cs

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public uint InstrumentID { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public uint Volume { get; set; }

        public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes)
        {
            int oldMinutes = TimeStamp.Minute;
            int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

            DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(TimeStamp.Year, TimeStamp.Month, TimeStamp.Day, TimeStamp.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

            return startOfPeriod;
        }
    }
```

myfunction.cs

```
public static void ExecuteProcess([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
            var queryable = Program.documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyObject>
            (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("tickerDatabase", "tickerContainer"), option).ToList();


            var resultSet = queryable.GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(5))
               .Select(gr =>
              new
              {
                  StartOfPeriod = gr.Key,
                  Low = gr.Min(item => item.Low),
                  High = gr.Max(item => item.High),
                  Open = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).First().Open,
                  Close = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).Last().Close
              });

            var my5min = resultSet.LastOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("time " + my5min.StartOfPeriod + " open " + my5min.Open + " high " + my5min.High + " low " + my5min.Low + " close " + my5min.Close);
```

Let me explain issue with 1 minutes data (though I originally want 5 minute).

Below are the sample records -

```
List<MyObject> test = new List<MyObject>();
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 01) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2933, High = 2933, Low = 2933, Close = 2933, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 01) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2936, High = 2936, Low = 2936, Close = 2936, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 03) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2944, High = 2944, Low = 2944, Close = 2944, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 05) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2944, High = 2944, Low = 2944, Close = 2944, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 08) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 10) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 15) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2932, High = 2932, Low = 2932, Close = 2932, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 25) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 26) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 28) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2932, High = 2932, Low = 2932, Close = 2932, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 30) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2941, High = 2941, Low = 2941, Close = 2941, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 32) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 35) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2941, High = 2941, Low = 2941, Close = 2941, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 40) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2937, High = 2937, Low = 2937, Close = 2937, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 42) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 45) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2937, High = 2937, Low = 2937, Close = 2937, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 48) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 50) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2939, High = 2939, Low = 2939, Close = 2939, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 52) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2937, High = 2937, Low = 2937, Close = 2937, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 54) });
            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2935, High = 2935, Low = 2935, Close = 2935, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 01, 56) });

            test.Add(new MyObject() { Open = 2935, High = 2935, Low = 2935, Close = 2935, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 02, 12) });
```

Passed 1 minutes as a parameter to GetStartOfPeriodByMins(1) -

Here records are for time 10:1:56 and 10:2:12.

Now you can observe last we will get 2 record set into resultSet

If timer trigger function is not run at specific time it will only take average of last record for 10:2:12 and it is not right

So question is how to match running time?

Same will happen with 5 minutes as well.

Output of above sample data for 1 minutes

[image]

So we need to ensure data should be complete from that timeframe.

Comment: `Task.Run(...).Wait();` No. No. No. No no no no no. Make that `private static async Task` and await `CreateDocumentAsync`.

Comment: just to run it in different thread i did this

Comment: Different from what? And it's async anyway.

Comment: oh yea right will change it sure

Comment: _"if timer job runs 1 minute late"_ - what do you mean exactly here? How would it be "late"?

Comment: i mean currently i'm running it manually not hosted testing it but if such scenario happens let me explain it into question with sample data

Comment: Maybe you can address some more doubts along the way: `var resultSet = queryable.GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(5))` isn't this causing an error? I would have expected it to ... and also `int oldMinutes = TimeStamp.Minute;` <- Where is `Timestamp` coming from?

Comment: GetStartOfPeriodByMins is inside class MyObject where my all properties are

Comment: now updated all code snippet it will run too :) pls try to help thanks in advance

Comment: I think "GroupBy" is not doing what you think it does ... but not 100% sure. I'd try with a `Where( x => x.TimeStamp >= DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))` or something like this.

Comment: its is working tested code with some static values it is working fine but issue is with timing as i shown into above sample if reading is at that specific time and it may got only 2-3 records of latest 5 minutes then result will be wrong so data it should take from 01 to 59 may few we can miss few points but not too much points

Comment: concern is how to insure data should be from 01 to 59

Comment: Ahhh, so you want _full_ minutes ...

Comment: yep because calculation  is based on that only we took data for minute or 5 minutes so it should take that data to find out high low open close...

Comment: i will run this code at 9:15AM we will get data from 9:15 onwards which i will save it into cosmos continuously. now at 9:20 timer function app will hit 1st time cosmos it should read data for last 5 minutes so that our function app code will find out open low high close of that data.
data should be taken from 9:15:00 to 9:19:59 :) kindly help to achieve this 
and this will happen thought out a day with next 5 minutes time slot as this is our contunous running job so all will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution here can be to leverage `_ts` property of documents. You can directly have a SQL query with `start date` and `end date` with 5 minutes span. In addition to this, you can save `start date` as `last used end date` in DB(negligible cost). The query shall look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c._ts <= 1601890740 AND c._ts >= 1601890585
```

Also note that, you will have to do some to and fro conversions of POSIX to DateTime.